# Failed to create timer on Jboss5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0, transactionscope

I am using EJB3.0 jboss5.1AS

I have some weird problem which didnt happen before.
I am trying to test my ejb stateless bean.

I used to simulate ejb call from a servlet which inside my ear(inside WAR project) and everything worked fine.

now we try to test this ejb via servlet which is outside the EAR from an extrnal tomcat server by doing EJB-call

and all of a sudden I get this exception:

```
7 May 12 13:13:11, ERROR DispactherBean:dispatchMsg:113 Exception. The error msg=Failed to create timer
javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to create timer
    at org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.TimerServiceImpl.createTimer(TimerServiceImpl.java:263)
    at org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.TimerServiceImpl.createTimer(TimerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceFacade.createTimer(TimerServiceFacade.java:83)
    at DispactherBean.dispatchMsg(DispactherBean.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at
```

....

I am triggering my timer this way:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(
{ DispactherBeanRemote.class })
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "DispactherBean")
public class DispactherBean implements DispactherBeanRemote, Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DispactherBean.class);

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

         public void someMethod()
         { 

            timerService.createTimer(MomConstants.TRX_TIMEOUT_PERIOD,"test");
         }
     ..
     }
```

I am calling this bean from tomcat/standalone this way:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jnp.interfaces");
            p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jboss.ip:1099"); 
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext(p);
            String lookupStr = "Mom/DispactherBean/remote-mom.beans.DispactherBeanRemote";

            DispactherBeanRemote dispactherBean = (DispactherBeanRemote) context.lookup(lookupStr);                 
        dispactherBean.someMethod();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you add more information on how you are calling bean from servlet, also have you tried using `SessionContext` to create timer.

Comment: Okie I will edit the question. and yes I tried SessionContext. didnt work as well .

Answer (score 0):

Need to add all jboss clients jars to the tomcat/jboss side.